# try to fetch data from mongdb but getting error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to fetch data that is associated with related login user but i am getting error like Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received.

### controller file:

```
function ManageProductController($http, $scope, $mdDialog, $document, $location, $localStorage)
{
     var vm = this;
     vm.uid = $localStorage._id;

     $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId:vm.uid}
        }).success(function(res) {
            //$scope.productlist = res;
            //console.log(res.result);
            vm.result=res.result;

            //vm.docs=res.docs;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
 }
```

### node file:

```
router.post('/manage-product', function(req, res){
    //console.log('I received get request');

    //console.log(req.body.userId);
    var um = ObjectId(req.body.userId);
    //console.log(um);
    var findProducts = function(db, callback) {

       var cursor =db.collection('proInfo').findOne({userId:um},function(err, docs){
          if(err){

             callback(new Error("Some problem"));
           }else{
            callback(null,docs);
        } 
         });

    };


    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
        findProducts(db, function(err,docs) {
          db.close();
          if(err) return res.json({result:null})
        else
       return res.json({result: docs  });
      });
    });
 });
```

I am getting result like following image

[image: error image]

My db looks like below image

[image: db image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your front-end code expects an array. You are giving it an object `{ response: your_resultant_array }`. That's why you're getting this error. To fix that, in your node.js file do this change:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
    findProducts(db, function(err,docs) {
      db.close();
      if(err) return res.json(err)
      else return res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Also, you're using `findOne`, which will return only one product. If you want multiple products use `find`. Something like this:

```
var findProducts = function(db, callback) {

   var cursor = db.collection('proInfo').find({userId:um}).toArray(function(err, docs){
      if(err) callback(new Error("Some problem"));
      else if(docs) callback(null,docs);
     });

};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, the error cleared but that user has 2 products but i am getting only one product in console.

Comment: That is because in your `findProducts` your are calling `findOne`. `findOne` always returns one document. If you want multiple documents, use `find`. Let me update the answer.

Comment: instead of `findone` if i used `find` it will shows following error        TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native)

Comment: i didn't use that anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says it all - "**Expected array but received**" - your JSON of a single object. And you're getting it because you use `findOne`, which means you get a single object instead of array of objects.

Comment: what should i do to get array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/manage-product', function(req, res){
    //console.log('I received get request');

    //console.log(req.body.userId);
    var um = ObjectId(req.body.userId);
    //console.log(um);
    var findProducts = function(db, callback) {

       var cursor =db.collection('proInfo').find({userId:um}).toArray(function(err, docs){
          if(err){

             callback(new Error("Some problem"));
           }else{
            callback(null,docs);
        } 
         });

    };

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
        findProducts(db, function(err,docs) {
          db.close();
          if(err) return res.json({result:null})
        else
       return res.json({result: docs  });
      });
    });
```

I used like this now i am getting what i want.

Comment: Forgot the `.toArray` part. Node Driver's `find` method, returns a cursor. `toArray` exhausts it to get an array.